# What while loop condition should I be using in my assignment?

Tags: java

My class project asks me to create code in Java that finds the minimum number of coins. I got that part. The instructor has asked us to make the program continue to run until someone enters a value of zero as input. I've done my research and looked at hows to do this and it seems that creating a while loop is the easiest way to achieve the result that I want. I've watched several tutorials on them and understand how they work but every single one says to create a

```
while (conditions)
```

but I have no idea what the conditions are or would be. I can make it work in other programs that are simple such as a counter that goes to 10 and then stops. But in my case I need the user input to stop the loop and cannot figure out how to do this.

My code is

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Coin {

    public static void main (String[] Args) {

        int quarters = 25;
        int dimes = 10;
        int nickles = 5;
        int pennies = 1;

        System.out.println("Enter in a number between 1-99");

        // "Input" Part of Code (Remember this and go back for reference)
        Scanner Userinput = new Scanner(System.in);

       int stuff = Userinput.nextInt();

       int q = stuff/quarters;
       stuff -= q*quarters;
       String A = "Number of Quarters:" +q;

       System.out.println(A);

       int d = stuff/dimes;
       stuff -= d*dimes;
       String B = "Number of Dimes:" +d;

       System.out.println(B);      

       int n = stuff/nickles;
       stuff -= n*nickles;
       String C = "Number of Nickles:" +n;

       System.out.println(C);       

       int p = stuff/pennies;
       stuff -= p*pennies;
       String D = "Number of Pennies:" +p;

       System.out.println(D);

       System.out.println("Thank you for Using My Program");
     }
```

I assume the while loop goes at the beginning but I am not sure what sort of conditions to add to make it work.

Comment: When should the loop exit?  Under what conditions?  (In English, not in code)

Comment: You need to repeat the program again and again?

Comment: Saint, if your question has been answered, you should accept one of the answers.  If you're still confused, post comments in reply to some of the answers for further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options, you can assign your stuff variable in your while condition and compare it. This way it will not enter the while loop if the user has entered 0. So in your case:

```
int stuff = 0;
while((stuff = Userinput.nextInt())!=0)
{
    int q = stuff/quarters;
    stuff -= q*quarters;
    String A = "Number of Quarters:" +q;


    System.out.println(A);


   int d = stuff/dimes;
   stuff -= d*dimes;
   String B = "Number of Dimes:" +d;

   System.out.println(B);


   int n = stuff/nickles;
   stuff -= n*nickles;
   String C = "Number of Nickles:" +n;

   System.out.println(C);


   int p = stuff/pennies;
   stuff -= p*pennies;
   String D = "Number of Pennies:" +p;

   System.out.println(D);
}
System.out.println("Thank you for Using My Program");
```

Your while loop will then continue to iterate until the user enters 0 (making stuff == 0).

Or you could check the user input within an infinite while loop, and use the 'break' command to exit a loop early. Sometimes the compiler will not allow you to use straight "true". So assign a boolean to true and use that instead.

```
boolean alwaystrue = true;
while(alwaystrue)
{
    int stuff = Userinput.nextInt();
    if(stuff==0)
    {
        break;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several different ways to handle this.  My personal preferred way for dealing with `while` loops that are intended to repeat until a user enters a certain value start with simply `while(true)`.  For example, let's say you want to quit if the user enters a value outside the 1-99 range:

```
while(true) {

    System.out.println("Enter in a number between 1-99");
    Scanner Userinput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int stuff = Userinput.nextInt();

    if(stuff < 1 || stuff > 99) {
        break;  //break is a keyword that exits the loop when a condition is met.
    }

    //do all your other stuff

}

System.out.println("Thank you for Using My Program");
```

This is certainly not the only approach, just my personal preferred approach for situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

a condition is just any boolean value (true or false). 
In your case you want to repeat your code until the user inputs 0. So a good condition would be if the user's input is 0, we don't want to loop anymore. Not sure how much more descriptive I can be without giving you the solution to the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

A condition statement is the stopping codition for the loop

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 25) {  // this stops that loop once i has reached 25
    // do something
    i++;
}
```

In your case you want

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (input != 0) {  // loop stops when you get an input of 0
                      // in human language terms, while input does not equal 0, 
                      // do something. Or you could say, until input equlas 0,
                      // keep doing something
   // so somtheing
   input  =  scanner.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are confused about what goes in the conditions section? In Java you need to have an expression that can evaluate to true or false. While loops will continue to execute every time their condition gets evaluated to true. In your case, you want to loop until the user enters 0.

```
while(input != 0){
   /*Code goes here*/
}
```